# Import different files based on where script is being called from

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have a file `global_params.py` which defines some global parameters that are used by a script `client_script.py`.

Now `client_script.py` can be called from the terminal, or it can be called from another python script `caller.py`. When it's called from the terminal I want the global parameters to be loaded from `global_params.py` I can do that with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from global_params import *
```

When `client_script.py` is called by `caller.py` how do I make it load global parameters from another file, say `global_params_2.py`

Comment: I would say `elif` instead of `else`  (in case I need to call it from more than just two places), What I'm asking is what should the condition in front of the `elif` be for calls from different places (terminal, one file, another file)

Comment: First of all, the whole idea seems wrong, still, separating in case of `"__main__"` is kind-of acceptable. But don't detect where your module is imported from. That is entirely wrong design. If you import it X times from different places, Python is going to optimize it into only one import. Instead of that, why don't you say what you really want to do? This is a classical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: As I said in the question, I want some global configuration variables to be loaded from different files depending on where the script is being called form.

Comment: Well then do it explicitly `def get_configuration(config_name)` which returns a configuration (e.g. a `dict`) depending on config name. Then use a different config name from different places. No `import *` is needed for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__name__` has the name of the caller, it is `__main__`  if you call `client_script.py` from the terminal, and the name of the calling script if it is called from another script. If `client_script.py` is called from within `caller.py`  then `__name__` is `caller`

So in your case this should do what you want:

```
if __name__ == 'caller':
    from global_params_2 import *
```